# How to let Selenium identify RFT script

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, rft

We have been using RFT as the automated testing tools before, and have accumulated tens of thousands of automation test case scripts, now we need to upgrade to the Selenium tool, is there any way to let Selenium execute RFT script?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute RFT scripts from the command-line and parse the HTML output log to determine if the test passed or failed; I'm not overly familiar with Selenium but it might be able to do that.

Comment: Thank you @Yamikuronue。Yes，Selenium can really realize your ideas.is good.But I don't want to use two tools for automated testing。Is there a tool can be convert RFT scripts to Selenium script directly . or do some adaptation to the RFT scripts，let it run in the Selenium environment。

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert RFT scripts into Selenium scripts, since they work in a completely different way.
You basically have to rewrite everything from scratch.

Take this opportunity to review all your automated tests. Maybe some more test analysis can lead to a better test design, reducing the number of scripts and discovering areas with too much cover and areas not well covered by testing.
You can get some help in [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for @Alessandro Da Rugna's suggestion。
I will try to do some adaptation on the rft script, see if I can make it work。

Answer (score 0):

Because RFT need Obj Map file to identify object,RFT script is not only a java file,you can  check that there is  many different postfix file with the same name about one RFT script,like .rftdef and  .rftxmap file.So  it's impossible to  convert RFT scripts to Selenium script.my advice is as 
Yamikuronue said to use RFT commandline  to run RFT scripts ,or if you don't like two tools, you  can  try put Selenium script into RFT environment,import selenium jar ,and selenium may playback cause RFT is also eclipse IDE,this is just my idea,i haven't put  it into practice